# Compiling code that uses socket function bind() with libcxx fails

Tags: c++, c++11, bind

I am using the new libcxx library and I have a code that calls the socket function `bind()`. The problem is that when I type `using namespace std;` the compiler gives me an error for the following code:

```
int res = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&myAddr, sizeof(myAddr));
```

The error using clang (svn build):

```
error: no viable conversion from '__bind<int &, sockaddr *, unsigned long>' to 'int'
 int res = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&myAddr, sizeof(myAddr));
```

I think that the problem is that `using namespace std;` brings the function `std::bind()` from the header `<functional>` to the scope (although the header is not included). As I am using a third party library that uses the entire namespace std I can't easily change the class names to fully qualified names.

I was wondering whether this is a problem in the implementation of the library or whether there are some new rules in C++11 that might potentially break an old code that uses `bind()`. Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Roman

Comment: What do you mean when you say that the third party library uses the entire namespace std?

Comment: I mean that it has `using namespace std;` in some of the files.

Comment: Presumably in the source files only and not in the headers? That should not affect you at all.

Comment: @Troubadour : Presumably in the headers, otherwise he wouldn't be affected. Personally, I'd just shoot the library author who did that. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: "The problem is that when I type using namespace std;" suggests not. I'm trying to ascertain why the OP thinks he "can't easily change the class names to fully qualified names.". I just don't understand that sentence.

Comment: I was talking about editing the source of the library actually, but that does not matter. Problem is that I would have to change the names every time I upgrade to a new version of the lib or persuade the lib author to do it himself. But as templatetypedef provided me with a simple solution (one single change) the library author was ok with that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This isn't a problem in the implementation of the libraries.  C++11 introduced its own **[`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)** function into `namespace std`, which is used to bind parameters to functions and support a bit of higher-order programming.

The reason for having `namespace std` is to help prevent new library functions and classes from causing breaking changes in existing code.  The reason for this is that everything has a name starting with `std::`, which prevents name collisions.

However, if you write `using namespace std;` in your program, you're exposing yourself to potential breaking changes like this one, since the free function `bind` and the function `std::bind` can't necessarily be disambiguated.

To fix this, you can call `bind` as `::bind` to make clear that it's in the global namespace, or you can remove the `using namespace std;` at the top of the program.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Finally I understood whats going on with bind not returning int.