# Why is the Mac OS specified TCP port not listening?

Tags: c++, macos, tcp, port, listen

I have a problem.

I wrote program in C++, specified port 60000.

```
m_pConn.sin_port = htons( 60000 );
```

and then, when program (TCPFileSe) started, I noticed that LISTENING port is not 60000.

Here is my listening port list..

```
christof-kims-Mac:~ christof-kim$ lsof -i | grep LISTEN
rapportd    639 christof-kim    3u  IPv4 0x1b8366a443833957      0t0  TCP *:49234 (LISTEN)
rapportd    639 christof-kim    4u  IPv6 0x1b8366a4437c0def      0t0  TCP *:49234 (LISTEN)
**TCPFileSe 24454 christof-kim    3u  IPv4 0x1b8366a446445957      0t0  TCP *:50087 (LISTEN)**
```

when I program second started..

```
christof-kims-Mac:~ christof-kim$ lsof -i | grep LISTEN
rapportd    639 christof-kim    3u  IPv4 0x1b8366a443833957      0t0  TCP *:49234 (LISTEN)
rapportd    639 christof-kim    4u  IPv6 0x1b8366a4437c0def      0t0  TCP *:49234 (LISTEN)
**TCPFileSe 24647 christof-kim    3u  IPv4 0x1b8366a446445957      0t0  TCP *:50117 (LISTEN)**
```

I don't understand why LISTENING port is not 60000.

Could you help me why LISTENING port is 50087, 50117?
Or, Mac OS is Not supported specified port???

I need for specified port (e.g 60000).

This code is just writed language c++ for Mac OS 10.13.6.
I've tried on Mac OS console line tool.

```
sockaddr_in m_pConn;

m_pConn.sin_family = AF_INET;
m_pConn.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "0.0.0.0" );
m_pConn.sin_port = htons( 60000 );

bind(m_nSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &m_pConn, sizeof(m_pConn));
socklen_t len = sizeof(m_pConn);

// Listen on the socket.
if ( listen( m_nSocket, 1 ) == -1 )
    printf( "Error listening on socket.\n");
```

Comment: What was `errno` when `bind()` returned -1?

Comment: I missed errno when I returned bind -1.

Comment: I solved the problem!! thx  user207421.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I used `using namespace std`.

```
//using namespace std;
```

So, I added the following code, and it then worked.

```
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;
```

Maybe the issue is related to this:
[Compiling code that uses socket function bind() with libcxx fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035294/compiling-code-that-uses-socket-function-bind-with-libcxx-fails)

Comment: When using std and bind, port listening is does not matching.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He was calling `std::bind()`, which is a C++ library thing, instead of `::bind()`, which is the TCP API.

Comment: @user207421 [I'm impressed that it compiled.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d914e861c70c3a14)

Comment: Could be an ancient stdlib implementation I suppose (i.e. pre [this](https://gitlab.indel.ch/thirdparty/gcc/commit/30be0cc7dddc46023a8b42827434408ddcf1b05c))

Comment: But it [still shouldn't compile](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6df694cdbc4b2eee) as there's no return type to deduce.